# Visual Studio 2010, C# and directx managed code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, directx

I am trying to use DirectX managed code for Visual Studio 2010 with C#.

I added the references from DirectX from the following path C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\DirectX for Managed Code\1.0.2902.0

Now every time I try to run a program I will get a Delay Notification saying that "Microsoft Visual C# 2010 is waiting for an operation to complete...", and the program is frozen forever.
I need to close it from task manager.

I need help to solve this problem.

Comment: It was discontinued a long time ago.  You also have a very early build of it, .NET 1.0 time frame.  Quacks like a loader lock problem.  Cut your losses, SlimDX and SharpDX are open source projects that wrap DirectX and are being maintained.

Comment: So you say that I should use SlimDX or SharpDX instead of Directx?

Comment: Not in stead of DirectX (they are both DirectX wrappers), in stead of "DirectX for Managed Code".

Comment: What about XNA, is it outdated?

Comment: @HansPassant SlimDX has not been touched in years, SharpDX is actively maintained (last commit yesterday). I had a great experiences using SharpDX.

Comment: @Light_Warrior SharpDX is a managed wrapper for DirectX. It basically encapsulates the C++ directx api, to be used in C#. It also has a higer level abstraction similar to XNA, called "SharpDX toolkit". I can't comment on the toolkit, as I haven't used it, but I highly recommend the SharpDX DirectX wrapper.

Comment: XNA Game Studio does not support VS 2012, VS 2013, Windows Store, or Xbox One. It has limited support for Windows phone 8 (compat mode as a Windows phone 7 app).

Answer (score 0):

The legacy DirectX Managed Assemblies 1.1 are only compatible with .NET 1.1. and the .NET 2.0 runtime (i.e. 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5). They do not work with the .NET 4.x Framework which is what VS 2010 uses by default.

If you are looking to port existing Managed DirectX 1.1 assembly code, see [SlimDX](http://www.slimdx.org/).

For a new app [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) is an excellent choice and is supported on a newer 'modern' Microsoft platforms.

See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/12/09/directx-and-net.aspx).